# Which is the canonical base for the Space of Complex matrices $A\in \Bbb{C}^{n\times n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, vector-spaces, matrix-decomposition

Which is the canonical base for the Space of Complex matrices $A \in \Bbb{C}^{n\times n}$?

I know in real matrices $\in \Bbb{R}^n$, the canonical base is trivial, just $n$ vectors with a $1$ in the $i$-th component for the $i$-th vector. But for complex matrices, it would be something like a tensor, because we need to generate a complex entry in each component of the vector. Nevertheless, I would like to know which is the formalization of this idea.

Comment: I suppose you are considering the space of complex matrices over $\Bbb{C}$, am I right?

Comment: @Caffeine Yes I am considering that space of complex matrices  $A\in \Bbb{C}^{n\times n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is called “canonical”, but a natural basis of $\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ is $\{E_{ij}\mid1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n\}$ wher $E_{ij}$ is the $n\times n$ matrix whise entries are all $0$ except for the entry located at the $i$<sup>th</sup> line and the $j$<sup>th</sup> column, which is a $1$.

Comment: So, the basis would be the same as for the real matrices $A \in \Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$?. From my understanding, the base of the complex space has two elements {(0,1), (1,0)} and the base of the Real numbers has just one element {1}. So, it should be different also for the space of matrices over $\Bbb{R}^{n\times n} $ and $ \Bbb{C}^{n\times n}$... You are saying are the same right?

Comment: When you are talking about a complex space, the scalars *become* $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @obscurans Thanks, it is true.